# Vertical dataset to horizontal dataset in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

| ID | Age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 19 |
| 1 | 22 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 2 | 21 |

And I would like to turn it into this:

| Age | ID=1 | ID=2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | 1 | na |
| 20 | na | 1 |
| 21 | na | 1 |
| 22 | 1 | na |

How can I do that?

I have tried both with t() function and spread() but I was not able to arrive to a decent result

Comment: `mutate(quux, value = 1) %>% pivot_wider(Age, names_from = "ID")` (or using `reshape2`, with `transform(quux, value = 1) |> reshape2::dcast(Age ~ ID, value.var = "value")`). (The `quux` is the data.frame object.)

Comment: using the dplyr code I get the following error: Values from `value` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates.
* Use the following dplyr code to identify duplicates.
  {data} %>%
    dplyr::group_by(age, ID) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(n = dplyr::n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
    dplyr::filter(n > 1L)

Comment: consider `xtabs(~Age+ID, df)`

Comment: @user13195765, it works with the data as you provided it, so I don't konw what's different about your data. My guess is that you don't have the uniquness you expect in your data. Does `count(quux, ID, Age) %>% filter(n > 1)` return any rows?